# How can I define my form such that it's html starts with <div ...>?

Tags: django, django-forms

Currently, in forms.py, I have:

```
questionToProblemPreview = forms.CharField(label = "Preview", widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'id' : 'MathOutPut', 'readonly' : 'True', 'cols': 80, 'rows': 10}))
```

The resulting HTML in Django admin looks like this:

```
<div class="form-row field-questionToProblemPreview">
    <div>
        <label class="required" for="MathOutPut">Preview:</label>
            <textarea name="questionToProblemPreview" cols="80" rows="10" id="MathOutPut"        readonly="True" required>
</textarea>
    </div> 
</div>
```

How can I make it such that  `<textarea name="questionToProblemPreview" cols="80"...>` becomes instead `<div name="questionToProblemPreview" cols="80"...>`?

Answer (score 0):

I can share a simple solution i.e

In your templates customize the form

access the name or attr as-

`<div name="{{form.questionToProblemPreview.name}}" cols="{{form.questionToProblemPreview.field.widget.attrs.cols}}"...>`

If you need only one or two field like this then it can be use, otherwise you need to create a custom field for that.

Comment: I see. How can I position the div to be underneath the textarea form that I want?